# The magnetic pendulum model

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, oscillators

I'm reading about this thing called the magnetic pendulum experiment, and I got curious about the equations of motion governing it. Essentially, imagine a pendulum whose bob is made of a magnetic metal and placed above some magnets. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQeQwwXXa7A) for the actual experiment. I've seen this equation for the bob's acceleration when looking it up:

$\begin{align*} m\ddot{\mathbf{x}} = \sum_j \frac{\mathbf{r}_j}{(h^2 + \mathbf{r}_j \cdot \mathbf{r}_j)^{3/2}} - g\mathbf{x} - \mu\dot{\mathbf{x}} \end{align*}$

In this equation:

- $\mathbf{x}$ is the position of the pendulum bob in the x-y coordinate plane. (The bob is assumed to be locked to a plane some fixed height above the plane the magnets lie on.)
- $\mathbf{r}_j$ is the distance between the bob's position and that of the $j$th magnet, i.e. $\mathbf{r}_j := \mathbf{x}_j - \mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{x}_j$ is the center of the $j$th magnet.
- $h$ is the height of the bob above the magnets.
- $g$ is the kickback force of the pendulum (think Hooke's law).
- $\mu$ is friction/air resistance.
- $m$ is the bob's mass.
- We assume the magnets are of equal strength.

I'm trying to understand this equation and I understand most of it. From what I understand, the $-g\mathbf{x}$ term comes from Hooke's  law, and describes the force restoring the pendulum back to its state of rest. The $\mu\dot{\mathbf{x}}$ term just damps the velocity. We put it all together using Newton's second law.

However, I don't understand why the denominator in the summation is raised to the power of $\frac{3}{2}$. [This source](https://www.math.hmc.edu/%7Edyong/math164/2006/win/finalreport.pdf) says it's to eliminate the vertical component from what is obviously a distance formula in the equation, but I don't see why that is. From what I understand, magnetic force obeys Coulomb's law, which is essentially a type of inverse square law. I've read it has something to do with dipoles and an inverse-cube law. Is this true?

I asked this on Math Stack Exchange and didn't really get an answer, and someone suggested that I post it here. Please try to keep in mind that I don't know too much about electromagnetics. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the first paragraph you state _pendulum whose bob is made of a magnetic metal_ then in the last you state _given the bob is not magnetic_. Could this be what's causing confusion? The bob is magnetic.

Comment: What I meant is that the bob is not a magnet, but that it is magnetic.

Comment: Even if it's ferromagnetic it can still feel a force in the presence of magnetic field.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say.

Comment: 3/2 is because the force is equal to $~ \overrightarrow{F}=\dfrac{1}{\left| \overrightarrow{r}\right| ^{2}}\dfrac{\overrightarrow{r}}{\left| \overrightarrow{r}\right| }=\dfrac{\overrightarrow{r}}{\left| \overrightarrow{r}\right| ^{3}}$

Comment: Oh, that figures.